# How to Show the attributes of the table when I Select Item from ComboBoxColumn In DataGridView.?

Tags: vb.net

Supposedly I click the Item in ComboBox Column See [image: Pic]

Then the rest cell in a row must be fill with attributes of the table see [image: Pic]

Comment: it may due tto the binding problem, with that column ( if the collection of the combobox is different ), the comboBox binnded collection don't bind  with the gridColumn

Comment: For now I only tried to load the combobox...

Comment: my datagrid not bind to any data source because i just want the datagrid in the form to hold a data temporarily then I will save it later

Comment: call the grid binded value with new keyword , if collection = new collection like this call the method

Comment: can you showing me a sample code for that @SwethaVijayan

Comment: i will provide a sample code with winform and wpf () the methods are same you should change according to ur requirements

Answer (score 1):

```
in winforms
..............

 BindingList<listName> BindListNmae= new BindingList<listName>(); 
private void load()
{
gridView.DataSource= BindListNmae;// which is to be binded in the Maingrid
fieldName.Properties.DataSource= "your column binded value";
}

in wpf
..................

private ObservableCollection<CollectionName> products;     //--- products and produuct cColletion is Diferent
private ObservableCollection<collectionName> ProductCollection 


private void LoadData()
{
new ServiceClient().Using(channel =>
                {

                        products = channel.GetMethod();    // bind this products in the grid COlumn in design part                 
                        ProductCollection = channel.GetProductcollection();
                    }
                });

gvProductColelction.DataContext=ProductCollection;
}
```

Comment: if it is not help you .. paste your code in this i will go through it and , help you

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private sub dataGrid_ComboBoxColumn_dataBound()
      conn = New MySqlConnection
        Try
            With conn
                If .State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                    .ConnectionString = StrConnection()
                    .Open()

                End If
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        Dim dr2 As MySqlDataReader
        Dim com As New MySqlCommand
        com.CommandText = "SELECT Product_Code,Product_ID, Product_Name FROM Produc_List WHERE Supplier_ID ='" & cmbSupIndex.Text & "' ORDER BY Product_ID ASC"

        com.Connection = conn

        dr2 = com.ExecuteReader


        While dr2.Read()
            Ctype(dtItem.columns(2), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).Items.add(dr2("Product_name"))
        End While

        dr2.Close()
        conn.Close()
End sub
```

Comment: my code only to bound the .comboBoxColumn @Swetha Vijayan